# What are all the ways you can print strings using a loop in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops

```
char testArray[][50] = {"Mango", "Strawberry", "Bannana", "Cherry"};

for(int x = 0; x<testArray; x++){
    printf("%s", testArray[x]);
}
```

I am trying to find all the ways I can print strings using loops in c language. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't work. `%c` requires the argument to be a `char`, but `testArray[x]` is `char[50]`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in your for loop is incorrect. There are compared an integer with a pointer.

```
for(int x = 0; x<testArray; x++){
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also the call of `printf` invokes undefined behavior because there is used an incorrect conversion specifier to output a string.

```
printf("%c", testArray[x]);
       ^^^^
```

You could write

```
char testArray[][50] = {"Mango", "Strawberry", "Bannana", "Cherry"};
const size_t N = sizeof( testArray ) / sizeof( *testArray );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%s\n", testArray[i] ); // or just puts( testArray[i] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks man help me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pointers:

```
#define TSIZE(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int main(void) {
    char testArray[][50] = {"Mango", "Strawberry", "Bannana", "Cherry"};

    for(char (*x)[50] = testArray; x < &testArray[TSIZE(testArray)]; x++){
        printf("%s\n", *x);
    }
}
```

or of you want to use `%c` format:

```
int main(void) {
    char testArray[][50] = {"Mango", "Strawberry", "Bannana", "Cherry"};

    for(char (*x)[50] = testArray; x < &testArray[TSIZE(testArray)]; x++)
    {
        char *p = x[0];
        while(*p)
            printf("%c", *p++);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification much appreciated.